# When using CSS width : 102%, on a range slider google chrome doesn't show effect I'am looking for

Tags: html, css

I'm able to achieve [this effect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fz0Sn.png), "the white range track going beyond yellow circle" on an HTML range slider using CSS, but when viewing the slider on google chrome the sliders track don't show the same effect as show [in the images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fz8Mh.png).

here is my code for the range slider :

```css
.slider {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    width: 615px;
 margin: 25px 0;
    height: 15px;
 border-radius: 5px;
    background: transparent;
    outline: none;
    opacity: 0.7;
    -webkit-transition: .2s;
    transition: opacity .2s;
 text-align: center;
}

.slider input {
    text-align: center;
}

.slider:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}

.slider::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
 height: 5px;
 width: 102%;
    cursor: pointer;
 background: #ffffff;
}

.slider::-moz-range-track {
 height: 5px;
 width: 102%;
    cursor: pointer;
 background: #ffffff;
 
}

.slider::-webkit-slider-thumb {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
    width:  18px;
    height: 18px;
 margin: -7px 0  0;
 border: 0;
 border-radius: 50%;
    background: #F2E375;
    cursor: pointer;
 border: 0 !important;
}

.slider::-moz-range-thumb {
    width: 18px;
    height: 18px;
 border: 0;
 border-radius: 50%;
    background: #F2E375;
    cursor: pointer;
 border: 0 !important;
}
.background {
    background:#64c2c8;
}
```

```html
<html>
    <body class="background">
        <input type="range" min="1" max="5" value="1" class="slider" id="mySlider" steps="1">
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Padding worked for me:

```
padding-left: 10px;
padding-right: 10px;
```

```css
.slider {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    width: 615px;
    margin: 25px 0;
    height: 15px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background: transparent;
    outline: none;
    opacity: 0.7;
    -webkit-transition: .2s;
    transition: opacity .2s;
    text-align: center;
}

.slider input {
   text-align: center;
}

.slider:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}

.slider::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
    height: 5px;
    width: 102%;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
    background: #ffffff;
}

.slider::-moz-range-track {
    height: 5px;
    width: 102%;
    cursor: pointer;
    background: #ffffff;
}

.slider::-webkit-slider-thumb {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
    width:  18px;
    height: 18px;
    margin: -7px 0  0;
    border: 0;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: #F2E375;
    cursor: pointer;
    border: 0 !important;
}

.slider::-moz-range-thumb {
    width: 18px;
    height: 18px;
    border: 0;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: #F2E375;
    cursor: pointer;
    border: 0 !important;
}
.background {
    background:#64c2c8;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body class="background">
    <input type="range" min="1" max="5" value="1" class="slider" id="mySlider" steps="1">
</body>
</html>
```